# How to find correct column to use in one worksheet for formula in another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, find, cross-reference

I receive daily a [Microsoft Excel 2013] spreadsheet of information from which I copy the data into my own. Another 'Output' sheet extracts from that the info I need and presents it in the way I need to see it using formulas.

This works fine when the worksheet I'm sent has data in the same columns my 'Output' sheet expects it in. Unfortunately although the received spreadsheet has all the data I need, it isn't always presented in the same order -  i.e. which column a particular element is shown in varies. I can't control how I receive the data.

Can anyone advise how within my 'Output' formula I can say "find the correct column, and use the data in this one'?

This shows what I need to achieve. The 'Output' sheet contains the formulas and the data I paste in simply by copy and pasting from a received data sheet. 
Received Data

[image]

But the sheet I receive might have the same data but in a different order, so when I just copy and paste, this happens:

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is that regardless of which column order the incoming data is in I can just copy and paste it as is into my 'Data' sheet.

In the real world the incoming spreadsheet has thirty or more columns, and my 'Output' sheet contains a lot of different formulae, so I'm trying to come up with a method by which I don't have to manually rejig the formulae each day or rearrange the order of the incoming data, as both of these options are very time consuming.

I'd like to achieve this if possible using formulas not VBA, primarily because I'm not au fait with using VBA and (a) learning how to do it would consume even more time and (b) once I realise how much more I could do once I know it, bang goes the rest of my life! :-)

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've tried searching for an answer but everything seems to take me to finding specific data not specifying where to look.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Example data must be **in the question** not an external link. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: Thanks David. Was trying to pre-empt the comment 'Show us what you mean'.  This might explain why I couldn't find a way to simply upload an example file here. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can just use the received Data as it is and just change Note From, you can use the following:
in an empty cell F10 external to the data in the output sheet you can find the column number of Notes by using:
`=MATCH("Notes",Data!$A$1:$F$1,0)`

where Data!$A$1:$F$1 is the first Row (Header) of Data sheet

Then in the column Note From use the formula:

`=LEFT(VLOOKUP($A2,Data!$A$2:$F$9,F$10,FALSE),FIND(" ",VLOOKUP($A2,Data!$A$2:$F$9,F$10,FALSE),1))`

you can use also the same match for any other column

in B10 write `=MATCH(B1,Data!$A$1:$F$1,0)`    under cost column(B1)
in B2 write `=VLOOKUP($A2,Data!$A$2:$F$9,B$10,FALSE)` to have the cost of the Part No in A2 in the output sheet

[image]

Comment: Wow! Awesome! Sorry it took so long to reply. When I saw your answer last night I thought 'No, I need to sleep before trying that'. Glad I did - it made total sense and worked almost perfectly on the example I created. 'The 'almost' comes from a circular reference message when I apply the modified formula to column A. But, hey, that's the one column where I know there will be a unique reference, and even if I end up needing to change where that column's data comes from now and then, that will be really quick and easy to do. I'm now off to apply the answer to my real spreadsheet. Thanks EVERso.

Comment: you are right about column A you need to copy paste it in the right place before applying the formula for other columns, it is actually the unique important index column